# Sorting attributes by date using Amazon DynamoDB database

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I’m currently using dynamoDB for handling a large number of data related to a retail store. It is coming difficult for me to sort the products based on the most purchased, date etc.

Now when any customer make a purchase or browsed a product I’m storing product ID, URL, name, image, purchases, browsed on database using following schema.

Table Schema :

```
hashKey : storeID 
    rangeKey : productId (Number)
    productURL : http://example.com
    productName : example product 
    productImage : http://example.com/productimage.jpg 
    purchased (LSI - Local Secondary Indexes) : 20 (Number)
    browsed (LSI - Local Secondary Indexes) : 45 (Number)
```

Using above schema, I can sort (max to min / min to max) based on product ID, purchases and browsed products.

For example, using purchased(LSI ) I can sort most purchased product to least purchased product and vice versa. (We will get all relative attributes like productURL, productName, productImage etc).

However I want to implement a system which can support date as well as the sorting functionality.

**For example -  if  the user wants to sort the products which was most sold last week or least purchased last month I should be able to get the results.**

Can anyone please suggest a better implementation to achieve this?

Comment: Where are you storing the date in the above schema?

Comment: Above schema doesn't have date.. Using Local secondary index I am sorting. I want to implement functionality using date filter.